# Processing checkbox input in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, laravel

I'm Using Laravel 4 to make an application. There is a form to create an event, which is then processed in the Controller.

This is my code for the checkboxes:

```
@foreach($value['value'][$i] as $key1=>$value1)
    {{ Form::checkbox('amenities[]', $value1) }}
@endforeach
```

I have a function in my Controller, which has this code:

```
$amenitiesALL = array();
$amenitiesALL = Input::get('amenities');
foreach($amenitiesALL as $amenities)
{
    $amenity = new EventAmenities;
    $amenity::create(array('EVENT_ID' => $eventID, 'EVENT_AMENITIES_ID' => $amenities));
}
```

It's raising an error every time
`[2014-06-29 13:55:46] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array' in E:\wamp\www\bt\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php:973`

How do I make the variable take the input from the form as an array?
Any other suggestions would also help.

Comment: What does your model look like. EVENT_AMENITIES_ID is a column that refers to another table/model?

Comment: @Unnawut       I have tables USER_EVENTS and AMENITIES, AND EVENT_AMENITIES is a pivot table. And yes, foreign keys are in play referencing both tables. 
I'll let you know the flow, which now that i think of it, is important to know.
I store the input of amenities (checkboxes) in a variable (i think array), and fetch the event_id from USER_EVENTS, and then for each amenity, i insert the event_id and the amenity in the EVENT_AMENITIES table.
Should that pose any problem?

Comment: Can you check that $eventID and $amenities are already integers? Or a stacktrace from your `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` would also help. I don't know why it's trying to call `preg_replace()`. `Model::create()` doesn't seem to need a preg_replace.

Comment: @Unnawut I did `$amenities = ''.$ameneties.'';` 
And then it worked!

Comment: That's interesting. Do post as an answer. Would be nice if you could tell us what you get when you `var_dump($ameneties)` as well.

Comment: @Unnawut       This is strange. var_dump gives `string '1' (length=1)` even before adding the `''.$amenities.''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$amenity = new EventAmenities;
$amenity::create(array('EVENT_ID' => $eventID, 'EVENT_AMENITIES_ID' => $amenities));
```

To

```
$amenity = EventAmenities::create(array('EVENT_ID' => $eventID, 'EVENT_AMENITIES_ID' => $amenities));
```

Or if you want to store it, declare `$amenity = array()` outside the loop and change the above to

```
$amenity[] = EventAmenities::create(array('EVENT_ID' => $eventID, 'EVENT_AMENITIES_ID' => $amenities));
```